# Let $x,y$ in a group G with odd order. Let $x^2=y^2$. Show that $x=y$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $x,y$ in a group G with odd order. Let $x^2=y^2$. Show that $x=y$.

Comment: Nice tagging, mate.

Comment: Can you show us your attempts so far?

Comment: Now that you have a good answer this comes a bit late, but if you have problems attacking a question like this my advice is to start thinking about a special case. Here you can't get smaller than $|G|=3$, which means that the group is cyclic of order three. What happens there? Can you extrapolate?

Answer (score 6):

Let $k$ be such that $2k + 1$ is the order of $G$. Since $x^2 = y^2$, $(x^2)^{k+1} = (y^2)^{k+1}$.

$$ x^{2k +2} = x\cdot x^{2k+1} = y\cdot y^{2k+1} = y^{2k +2}$$

Since  $2k + 1$ is the order of $G$, $x^{2k+1} = y^{2k+1} = 1_G$ and $$x = y.$$